# How to get custom price format (with 3 Precision) in magento

Tags: php, magento, number-formatting

hope someone can help.

Need number_format to show 3 decimal on this.... (actualy 2)

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()/$_product->getAnzeigeMenge()) ?>
```

alway used number_format($_value, 3,",",".") but dont know how to get this to work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
[magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Data.php
```

**add below function**

```
public function customformatPrice($price)
{
        return $this->getQuote()->getStore()->customformatPrice($price);
}
```

**add below function in [magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php**

```
public function customformatPrice($price, $includeContainer = true)
   {
          if ($this->getCurrentCurrency()) {
          //sets the floating point precision to 3 points

          return $this->getCurrentCurrency()->format($price, array('precision'=>3),     $includeContainer);

         }  
         return $price;
   }
```

you can use above like

```
//magento default call
echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(3000.1231);//Rs3,000.12
echo "<br>";
//customized function call
echo Mage::helper('checkout')->customformatPrice(3000.12313);//Rs3,000.123
```

actually you can direct modify the **formatPrice()** in [magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php  but as you want both format we create custom function

hope this helpful for you

Comment: Thank u verry verry much. Thats it ;)

Comment: I highly discourage people from changing core files, that's a bad practice and then prevent you from upgrading your Magento !

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

Try Using this,

```
echo number_format($_value, '2', '.', ',')
```

or

```
echo number_format($_value, '3', '.', ',')
```

Also please check for

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I know about this, but this is not my question. How i display <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()/$_product->getAnzeigeMenge()) ?> to be with 3 decimals  Thank u

Comment: use <?php echo number_format($_product->getData('custom_attribute_name_here'), 2); ?> number format function otherwise i have to change in mage lib files for currency

Comment: I think this would work but not help in this place. Iam using this on cart/checkout page to divide formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice() with my custom attribut (see my above code). The Only way i have getting this divide funktion to work is with this methode. Only on this i need to display 3 decimals on all other i need 2

Answer (score 0):

open [magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php

```
public function formatPrice($price, $includeContainer = true)
   {
          if ($this->getCurrentCurrency()) {
          //sets the floating point precision to 3 points

          return $this->getCurrentCurrency()->format($price, array('precision'=>3),     $includeContainer);

         }  
         return $price;
   }
```

**Note:- change array('precision'=>3) instead of array()**