# Custom Price Display Precision without Roundings in Magento

Tags: php, magento

On this Question Member shivam helps me to figure out a problem for a custom price format...

[How to get custom price format (with 3 Precision) in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895693/how-to-get-php-number-format-get-work-in-magento)

**Here i use now Precision of 3**

```
public function customformatPrice($price, $includeContainer = true)
   {
          if ($this->getCurrentCurrency()) {
          //sets the floating point precision to 4 points

          return $this->getCurrentCurrency()->format($price, array('precision'=>3),     $includeContainer);

         }  
         return $price;
   }
```

But i used a Round Precision of 4

```
public function roundPrice($price,$roundTo=4)
 {
 return round($price, $roundTo);
 }
```

All works fine when i use Backend Input Price Like 9.2400 € The Output in frontend are fine then. But When i input in backend something like 9.2450 € the output on fronend are roundet. It seams that i miss somewhere to round price the right way.

This Code i use for List view... (wrong Display in Roundings):

```
<?php echo  ''.Mage::helper('checkout')->customformatPrice($_minimalPriceDisplayValue /1.19 /$_bbase_qty, false) ?>
```

This Code i use for Product View. (Perfekt Roundings) But i cants use this code in List or Price phtml.

```
<span class="price"><?php echo ''.Mage::helper('checkout')->customformatPrice(min($product_price)*1.19/($_bbase_qty),true,false); ?></span>``
```

Hope someone can help me Figuring out where is the problem in roundings or can help me how can i use the last code in  directly in list.phtml.

Thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0):

open file `[magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php`

```
    public function roundPrice($price)
    {
        return round($price, 4);//change 2 to 4
    }

    public function customformatPrice($price, $includeContainer = true, $options=array())
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentCurrency()) {
            return $this->getCurrentCurrency()->format($price,$options, $includeContainer);
        }
        return $price;
    }


echo Mage::helper('checkout')->customformatPrice(3000.12313,true,array('precision'=>4));
```

hope this help you

**Note: Don't change in core files directly instead override it**

Comment: hi shivam, thank you for helping me again. Sory its not working for me. Dont know how but i fixed that in List view (with your code from before) . But only in Checkout tabels (price with Tax and without tax) it rounds to 2 decimal. Cant figure out why. I have change all to rounds to 4 decimal but nothing.